# Config KCFinder in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, tinymce, kcfinder

I'm using TinyMCE as text field and I need it be possible Making Image upload in it, and for that I am using KCFinder, Just What the Problem is that when I click in Upload Images , it appears only a box in White : the following initialization code to TinyMCE (Note : I'm programming in angular):

```
vm.tinymceOptions = {
    resize: false,
    height: 300,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: 'autolink link image preview fullscreen textcolor ',
    toolbar: 'undo, redo | styleselect  | cut, copy, paste | bold, italic, underline, strikethrough | subscript, superscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link image | preview, forecolor',
    file_browser_callback: function(field, url, type, win) {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: 'app/template/plugin/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce4&field=' + field + '&type=' + type,
            title: 'KCFinder - Caminho atual: ',
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            inline: true,
            close_previous: false
        }, {
            window: win,
            input: field
        });     
        return false;
    }
};
```

And that's what appears when I open the image upload in TinyMCE :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

config.php

// GENERAL SETTINGS

```
'disabled' => **true**,
'uploadURL' => "upload",
'uploadDir' => "",
'theme' => "default",
```

change
// GENERAL SETTINGS

```
'disabled' => **false**,
'uploadURL' => "upload",
'uploadDir' => "",
'theme' => "default",
```

Comment: I tried this config, but it doesn't worked, the sabe problem continues